# General formula for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^k r^n$ for arbitrary $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Is there a general formula for the above summation (in terms of $r$ and $k$)? I've read a very [helpful answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn?newreg=20ee7319a9514b4b8b87dbfcdaff7872) on the general formula for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n r^n$, and according to this answer, there was a general formula for arbitrary $k$; however, I couldn't find any references in there as to what it was.

Thanks in advance, all your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Per definitionem this is the polylog function $\text{Li}_{-k}(r)$. See e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: Are $k$ and $r$ both integers?