# Find the value that $\sum_{j\geqslant 1} j^k*2^{-j}$ converges to for $k \in {N}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Context:** I am trying to compute the expected value of a random variable $X$ whose PMF is given by $P_X(x)=(\tfrac12)^x$. This results in verifying if $\sum_{x\in{N}}x2^{-x}$ converges, and if so, to what value. I used the absolute convergence test and verified that this series converges. I also know from checking online calculators that this series converges to $2$.

Further, I need to find the variance of $X$ as well. I'm going about that by computing $E[X^2]$ which means I need to evaluate $\sum_{x\in{N}}x^2*2^{-x}$. I have no idea how to calculate that either, although I have found from the ratio test that this series also converges.

So, the question is, how to find the value for $\sum_{x\in{N}}x^k*2^{-x}$ for $k = 1,2$ and is there a formula for general $k\in{N}$.

Comment: Cf. [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you, any ideas on the similar looking series at the end? Updated the question

Comment: Do you know that you can compute $\mathbb EX$ as $G_X'(1)$ where $G_X(x) = \sum_{k\geqslant 0} \mathbb P(X=k)z^k$? In this case, you can compute that $G_X(x) = 2/(2-x)$ and continue with the computation of the expected value.

Comment: @Alborz For the variance, you can check it is $G_X'(1) +G_X''(1) - G_X'(1)^2$.

Comment: The standard approach is to find the value for a sum of a finite number of terms as a function of the number of terms, and then take the limit.

Comment: @AnneBauval This does not answer the follow up question regarding series $x^2*2^{-x}$

Comment: @Pedro MGF is definitely the way to go here. Thanks so much. If you'd like to post as an answer I will accept.

Comment: @Alborz Please focus on one question per post. Your main question was a duplicate and your "Follow up question" should be another post (certainly as well a mega-duplicate).

Comment: @AnneBauval I have edited the question.

Comment: For this now more general question, see [General formula for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^k r^n$ for arbitrary $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962997) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez before editing he had a geometric series, which works with that, and I meant for any geometric series, not any series